# Unable to find profile 'server' while running cometD load testing

Tags: maven-3, cometd, exec-maven-plugin

I'm trying to run cometD load testing following the steps listed [here](https://github.com/cometd/cometd#load-testing-cometd). I found out that `exec:exec` requires a property `exec.executable` which I'm providing as `mvn`. I'm seeing the error:

> [WARNING] The requested profile "server" could not be activated
>   because it does not exist.

How do you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the CometD documentation with a [section on benchmarking](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_benchmarking).